# SUMIFS With Text and Date Comparison

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

theoretically I want to sum the total income each employee made for all the businesses.

Like this:

Employee 1 = Biz 1 income + Biz 2 income + Biz 3 income, etc...
Employee 2 = Biz 1 income + Biz 2 income + Biz 3 income, etc...

Technically and based on the table below, I want to sum a range in column R starting from cell R14 where the text in column W starting from W14 is the same in column P starting from cell P14 **AND** the name of the month in column V starting from cell V14 is equal to a month in date in column N starting from cell N14.
*
(I included the date because this is part of a budget planner so I need to categorize the data based on months.)*

[image]

I used this formula:
**=SUMIFS(R14:R1013, P14:P1013, U14:U1013, TEXT(N14:N1013,"MMMM"),"="&T14:T1013)**

But it prompts me with the error: *Array arguments to sumifs are of different size*

What could be wrong here? Does someone have any idea?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/13045193). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75086073/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the text formula into ARRAYFORMULA to get the full column:

```
=SUMIFS(R14:R1013, P14:P1013, U14:U1013, ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(N14:N1013,"MMMM")),"="&T14:T1013)
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked!! Can you please explain why it didn't get the full width of the column without that ArrayFormula function?

Comment: TEXT has by default one value as input, when you enter a range it will only consider the first cell of that range and only return that. By adding ARRAYFORMULA or INDEX you're instructing TEXT to repeat its function all over the column

Answer (score 2):

You can get the totals for all months and all employees with `query()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { text(N13:N, "yyyy-MM"), O13:R }, 
    "select Col1, Col3, sum(Col5) 
     where Col3 is not not null 
     group by Col1, Col3", 
    1 
  ) 
)
```